# Exchange 2010 Enterprise CAL

Tags: exchange-2010, licensing

I feel kind of silly asking this question but I can't seem to find on how to check if I have enterprise CAL installed on Exchange 2010.  If I don't have one activated/installed, how do I activate enterprise CAL after purchasing it?

I know this is a simple question but I can't seem to Google for a definite answer.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't install licenses on Exchange, you just use what you have bought.

Comment: @pauska, you should make that an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @pauska said, Exchange 2010 doesn't care and isn't aware about licenses.  It's an honor system.  It will indicate in the Console GUI things that require an Enterprise CAL, but doesn't control features based on a CAL key.